# Getting the path of chosen image from gallery intent

Tags: java, android

Here's my function for the camera intent. I get the path by storing it first in a variable, and then using it to set the file destination.

```
private void openCameraIntent() {
    Intent pictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    file = new File(getExternalCacheDir(), "image_1.jpeg");
    fileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    pictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
    startActivityForResult(pictureIntent, REQUEST_CAPTURE_IMAGE);
}
```

However, I cannot do the same to gallery since the image that will be chosen is already there.

```
private void openGalleryIntent() {
    Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(gallery, REQUEST_CAPTURE_IMAGE);
}
```

Is there any way that I can get the path within this particular function?

Comment: There may not be a filesystem path that is useful to you, as `MediaStore` can access files that your app cannot. Use the `Uri` that you get back (e.g., with an image-loading library for populating an `ImageView`).

Answer (score 0):

You can instead use the recommended Activity Result API to pick up the image from gallery/storage which returns the URI of the picked image.

```
private val pickImage = 
registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()) { uri: Uri? ->
    yourMethod(uri)  
}
pickImage.launch("image/*")
```

Refer to [google docs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result) for more information